# Check if all 3 items in localStorage are present

Tags: if-statement, local-storage

I'm try to check for 3 items in localstorage and if the 3 items are present, redirect the page a new page.  Here are my items that get stored... these get stored as the user completes a task and if they complete all 3 then i want it to redirect them to a new page. I need a little guidance on how to write a function that checks for all 3 items and redirects to new page if they all are present.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 


    if(localStorage.getItem('mySmallTokenState') == 'open') {
                $(".complete-sm-off").addClass("complete-sm-on");


    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('myMedTokenState') == 'open') {
                $(".complete-med-off").addClass("complete-med-on");


    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('myLrgTokenState') == 'open') {
                $(".complete-lrg-off").addClass("complete-lrg-on");


    }



 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to a new page via javascript, all it takes is `window.location.href = URL_GOES_HERE;`

So if those are the localStorage checks you want to make, it is simply:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('mySmallTokenState') == 'open' && localStorage.getItem('myMedTokenState') == 'open' && localStorage.getItem('myLrgTokenState') == 'open') {
    window.location.href = URL_GOES_HERE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either

- nest the `if` statements, or
- combine them

Like this:

```
if (condition) {
  if (condition2) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Or

```
if (condition && condition2) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I combined them.